# Не работает проверка прав в Silex

Tags: php, silex

Проверяю права:

```
$app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_CHECK')
```

Возвращает false.

Получаю права пользователя

```
User->getRoles()
```

Возвращает

```
array (size=1)
0 => string 'ROLE_CHECK'
```

То есть у пользователя в правах они есть, но silex этого не знает в чем могут быть проблемы?

Comment: у вас определена роль ROLE_CHECK в $app['security.role_hierarchy']?

Comment: Была объявлена. Проблема в том что я сначала объявлял $app['security.role_hierarchy'], а потом основной security